# avoid logarithm of zero in pgfmathparse conditional assignment

Tags: tikz-pgf, conditionals, pgfmath, pgfmathparse

How can i avoid the error message `! Package PGF Math Error: I cannot calculate the logarithm of '0' (in ' 0>1 ? ln(0) : 0').` in the following code?
If possible, i want to evaluate the statement with one `\pgfmathparse{...}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\def\var{0}
\pgfmathparse { \var>1 ?   ln(\var)  : \var}\pgfmathresult
\end{document}
```

Comment: pgfmath evaluates both branches regardless of the condition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add another guard within the ln and give a safe value (1 here) it doesn't really matter what non-error value you use as it will not affect the result of the outer guard

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\def\var{0}
\pgfmathparse { \var>1 ?   ln(\var>1 ? \var:1)  : \var}\pgfmathresult

\def\var{1}
\pgfmathparse { \var>1 ?   ln(\var>1 ? \var:1)  : \var}\pgfmathresult


\def\var{2}
\pgfmathparse { \var>1 ?   ln(\var>1 ? \var:1)  : \var}\pgfmathresult

\end{document}
```